# jQuery Bootstrap Password Meter is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use a jQuery plugin for Twitter Bootstrap that provides rulesets for visually displaying the quality of a user's typed in password.

[This is how that plugin is working...](http://jsfiddle.net/mmXV5/563/)

But my problem is when I try to use it in my project it seems its not working properly. Texts are displaying accordingly, but meter bar is not working..

This is my **HTML -**

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username" class="col-sm-3 control-label">username</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="strenth" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Strenth</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <!-- <div id="messages"></div> -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-5">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
```

**My jQuery -**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  var options = {
    onLoad: function () {
      $('#messages').text('Start typing password');
    },
    onKeyUp: function (evt) {
      $(evt.target).pwstrength("outputErrorList");
    }
  };
  $(':password').pwstrength(options);
});
```

This is a [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/cefikicogu/1/edit?html,js,output) with my all code so far

Hope somebody may help me out..
Thank you.

Comment: Have you added all files which are used in jsfiddle?

Comment: @ManojKumawat, Yes I have.. Check my JSBIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your css path to 
`http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css` 
in `head` tag

[Check updated JSBIN here](http://jsbin.com/paravoyuvu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: is that css not equal to bootstrap css?

Comment: It is customized for meter bar.

Comment: yes it seems.. its overwriting bootstrap default styles. can we get styles only for meter bar from that file?